# Magento: Fatal error on loading product collection

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

Since a few days I am getting the following error on every page, where the product collection should be loaded:

> Call to a member function setStoreId() on a non-object in
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php on line 287

This is the function, where the error occurs:

```
    public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
        ->addCategoryFilter($this);
    return $collection;
}
```

I don't know what happened. I have tried to re-index everything and refreshed the cache, but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: you could diff the current core with fresh(magento instance) core folders and see, if something is changed

Comment: did you do an upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

```
Override /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php
```

and try this code may help you

```
public function getProductCollection()
{   
    $model->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getId());
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
        ->addCategoryFilter($this);
    return $collection;
}
```